# What does mean "just given"

Tags: meaning

What does mean "just given" in the following sentence: "Yet however obvious and irrefutable the Humean argument just given may appear, Kant's transcendental argument may be regarded as a direct assault on it."

Comment: *The argument **which was** just given may appear obvious and irrefutable*.

Comment: "argument just given" ... the argument was given before this, but not long before, shortly before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous mentioned. Another way of wording the sentence might be:

> Kant's transcendental argument may be regarded as a direct assault on the *previously mentioned* Humean argument; however obvious and irrefutable it may appear.

Comment: Hello, Atrate. Please look at the site protocols before answering inappropriate questions.